# WebAPI POST [FromBody] not binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm posting JSON to a WebAPI controller, but the properties on the model are not being bound.

```
public void Post([FromBody] Models.Users.User model) {
    throw new Exception(model.Id.ToString());
}
```

The raw request is as follows:

```
POST http://diva2.local/siteapi/User HTTP/: diva2.local
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length:: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://diva2.local
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.: application/json;charset=UTF: http://diva2.local/Users
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=: .ASPXAUTH=4; __RequestVerificationToken=Rp_hUysjwCjmsxw2

{"Id":3,"FirstName":"DIVA2","LastName":"User1","Username":"diva1","IsApproved":true,"IsOnlineNow":true,"IsChecked":true}
```

Every example I can find tells me this should work, but `model.Id == null`.

However, if I change the JSON to:

```
{User: {"Id":3,"FirstName":"DIVA2","LastName":"User1","Username":"diva1","IsApproved":true,"IsOnlineNow":true,"IsChecked":true}}
```

everything binds correctly.

This doesn't seem correct. I guess I could accept `JObject` as the parameter, and bind it up manually, but it feels like the above should Just Work (tm)?

**Update:**

I've changed the method to return the model, and I still receive null.

```
public Models.Users.User Post(Models.Users.User user) {
    return user;
}
```

And the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-MiniProfiler-Ids: ["a0fab514-d725-4d8f-9021-4931dc06ec4a","fdeeb9a8-9e36-41d8-91d3-5348e880e193","c1b4cc86-d7c3-4497-8699-baac9fa79bf1"]
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 21 May 2013 09:06:00 GMT
Content-Length: 4

null
```

Comment: Can you show the class definition for User?

Comment: #facepalm. No parameter-less constructor. Cheers for the insightful exception .net!

Comment: Is there such a thing as shame deleting a question?

Comment: Doh! Perhaps answer your own question with how you spotted the issue.

Comment: Yep, two hours down the drain when I remembered the default constructor wasn't there. Model binding requires a default constructor with no parameters. :(

Comment: This question has been edited, so I can't be sure it was always this way, but is `Content-Length:: application/json, text/plain, */*` correct?  Content-Length =/= Content-Type

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My user model did not have a parameter-less constructor.

Comment: This solved my problem too. I had a constructor that required parameters, and it was receiving null for all of the arguments. Adding a blank, parameter-less constructor fixed the problem.

Comment: Please see the answer from @Darin Dimitrov for the answer to the more common case

Comment: Why does is matter to have a parameter-less constructor? Btw it solved the problem.

Answer (score 25):

You are missing the **Content-Type** header in your Request.

Unfortunately even if you had checked for ModelState, we are not throwing any error information. However, the good news is that this behavior has been fixed for our coming release and you would see a 415 status code based response.

Web API requires the Content-Type header to find out the right formatter to deserialize the body to the parameter on the action.

Comment: Is `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` not valid?

Comment: hmm..from your original post above, there was no Content-Type header in it and it has something like `Content-Length:: application/json, text/plain, */*`..was this a typo?...also, have you tried checking if you have any model state errors...you could add this check and see `if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, this.ModelState));
            }`

Comment: Although a slightly different topic, Adding 'contentType' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8' to my jquery ajax post helped. So contentType made a big difference for me. It was being routed correctly in the controller, but the data parameter was always empty (until now).

Answer (score 19):

The following works perfectly fine for me:

Model:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    public bool IsOnlineNow { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public User Post(User user)
    {
        return user;
    }
}
```

Request:

```
POST http://example.com/api/values HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host: localhost:8816
Content-Length: 125

{"Id":3,"FirstName":"DIVA2","LastName":"User1","Username":"diva2user1","IsApproved":true,"IsOnlineNow":true,"IsChecked":true}
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Date: Tue, 21 May 2013 08:59:02 GMT
Content-Length: 125

{"Id":3,"FirstName":"DIVA2","LastName":"User1","Username":"diva2user1","IsApproved":true,"IsOnlineNow":true,"IsChecked":true}
```

As you can see everything is bound fine and dandy without the `User` prefix in the request JSON payload.

Be careful with the `model.Id`, because `id` might have a special meaning if you are using it in your route definitions as being part of the route. Do not confuse the 2 things (route parameters and those coming from the request body payload).

Comment: I've changed the method to return the POSTed model, as in your example, but am still receiving null.

Comment: Follow my example step by step. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 application using the basic template. Add a model (as shown in my answer). Add an API controller (as shown in my answer). Use Fiddler and invoke this controller using the payload shown in my answer. It works! I've done that millions of times and never had any issues.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The problem is that the { User: } label should not be provided in the request, the User object itself should be the root.

Comment: @Michael Brown Thank you.  This old comment helped me to figure out why I was receiving null.  I was providing the name of the class in the payload  "Person": [ {
      "Age": 53,
      "Name": "Marc Roussel"
    }
  ]

This is incorrect but this

{
 "Age": 53,
    "Name": "Marc Roussel"
}

This is correct.

Answer (score 7):

I found that my class had internal setters on all the properties.

Changing
    `public <property> {get; internal set;}`
to
    `public <property> {get; set;}`

fixed my issue

Comment: In my case I had forgotten to add the getter/setter completely.. Took me a while of scratching my head before I saw it! :P

Answer (score 0):

I had the `Serializable` and `xmlElement` tags on my class. Even though I specified JSON as the content type in requests and passed a JSON string it wouldn't work till those were removed... It also appears only the `serializable` attribute was causing the issue.