# Why is JsonObject Null?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, postman

I am sending a Post request to this function from Postman

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public string saveOrder([FromBody]JObject json)
    {
        //OrderSpecifications orderSpecifics = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderSpecifications>(json.ToString());

        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        //dictionary.Add("result", orderSpecifics.FirstName);

        return json.ToString();
    }
```

This is the screen shot of my postman.

[image: Postman Screenshot]

Why is the JSON object received in the function NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
The problem was that i was sending in the datetime object as it is in the json as well.
when i changed the following varaibles in the json . it worked fine.

```
"OrderDateTime":"2017-01-01 12:00:00.000",
"ConfirmedDateTime":"2017-01-01 12:00:00.000",
"DeliveryTime":"14:32",
"DeliveryMinutes":"12:32"
```

PS : do check your Json in the Json parser to check if it is in the right format if everything else seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue in model binding. ASP.Net is not able to convert the HTML body into the model expected on server side.  Check this post.

[WebAPI POST [FromBody] not binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665815/webapi-post-frombody-not-binding)

After that, also check this for best practices around model binding.

[Best practices for debugging ASP.NET MVC Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651085/best-practices-for-debugging-asp-net-mvc-binding)